# Open Multiples Dialogs in HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change this here so that I click on a div with a certain ID or Class and open a dialog with a certain ID?

```
$('body').on('click', '#id01', function() {
  var dlg = new DialogFx($('#itemDetails').get(0));
  dlg.toggle();
});
```

In this case, I can only click in the div "#id01" to open the dialog with "#itemDetails";

But I want to create "itemDetails2" "itemDetails3" and open by clicking in differents divs with differents IDs in the HTML.

Comment: so use a common class and data attribute to hold what element to get the details from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the ID (in the selector spot, after event's name) by a [class name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) or a customized attribute (aka [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)).

```js
$('body').on('click', '.someClass', function() {
    const dlg = new DialogFx($('#itemDetails').get(0));
    dlg.toggle();
});
```

Previously you must add the same class name to all related elements.

```
<span id="id01" class="someClass"></span>
<span id="id02" class="someClass"></span>
<span id="id03" class="someClass"></span>
...
```

Comment: I want to create multiple "itemDetails" dialogs. 
How am I going to open different dialogs with the same function by clicking in this span object, for example?

Comment: @pfx Do you want to create dialog boxes from elements whose ID are "id01", "id02", "id03" onwards? Or do you want to create a number of dialogs determined by a given value?

Answer (score 0):

Using a data attribute you can target elements and use the value to determine what element to select.

```js
$('body').on('click', '[data-triggers]', function() {
  const selector = $(this).data("triggers");
  const itemDetails = $(selector);
  console.log(itemDetails.text());
  // var dlg = new DialogFx($('#itemDetails').get(0));
  //dlg.toggle();
});
```

```css
.details { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details1" class="details">details 1</div>
<div id="details2" class="details">details 2</div>
<div id="details3" class="details">details 3</div>
<div id="details4" class="details">details 4</div>

<button data-triggers="#details1">1</button>
<button data-triggers="#details2">2</button>
<button data-triggers="#details3">3</button>
<button data-triggers="#details4">4</button>
```